# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las líneas entre dos patrones?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, awk

> Pregunta y respuesta basadas en mi propia pregunta y respuesta en [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38972736/1983854)

Tengo un fichero como el siguiente y me gustaría imprimir las líneas que aparecen entre los patrones `PAT1` y `PAT2`.

```
1
2
PAT1
3    - primer bloque
4
PAT2
5
6
PAT1
7    - segundo bloque
PAT2
8
9
PAT1
10    - tercer bloque
```

He leído [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17988756/1983854) pero tengo curiosidad por ver todas las posibles combinaciones, tanto imprimiendo los patrones como no.

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las líneas entre dos patrones?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Imprime líneas entre PAT1 y PAT2

```
$ awk '/PAT1/,/PAT2/' fichero
PAT1
3    - primer bloque
4
PAT2
PAT1
7    - segundo bloque
PAT2
PAT1
10    - tercer bloque
```

O, usando variables:

```
awk '/PAT1/{flag=1} flag; /PAT2/{flag=0}' fichero
```

¿Cómo funciona?

- La expresión regular `/PAT1/` encaja las líneas que contienen el patrón `/PAT1/`; análogamente, lo mismo pasa con `/PAT2/` y las líneas que contienen el patrón `/PAT2/`.
- `/PAT1/{flag=1}` inicializa el semáforo `flag` cuando el patrón `PAT1` aparece en una línea.
- `/PAT2/{flag=0}` apage el semáforo `flag` cuando el patrón `PAT2` se encuentra en una línea.
- `flag` es un semáforo y actúa como patrón. Cuando tiene valor `1`, se interpreta como valor Cierto y lanza la acción por defecto de `awk`, que consiste en ejecutar `{print $0}`, esto es, imprimir la línea actual. De esta forma, se imprimen todas las líneas que aparecen desde que `PAT1` aparece hasta que lo hace `PAT2`. Esto también imprime todas las líneas desde que `PAT1` aparece por última vez hasta el final del fichero, si no hay ningún `PAT2` antes.

## Imprime líneas entre PAT1 y PAT2 - sin incluir PAT1 y PAT2

```
$ awk '/PAT1/{flag=1; next} /PAT2/{flag=0} flag' fichero
3    - primer bloque
4
7    - segundo bloque
10    - tercer bloque
```

Esto utiliza `next` para saltar la línea que contiene el patrón `PAT1`, para que así no sea impresa.

Este uso de `next` se puede quitar reordenando los bloques: `awk '/PAT2/{flag=0} flag; /PAT1/{flag=1}' fichero`.

## Imprime líneas entre PAT1 y PAT2 - incluyendo PAT1

```
$ awk '/PAT1/{flag=1} /PAT2/{flag=0} flag' fichero
PAT1
3    - first block
4
PAT1
7    - second block
PAT1
10    - third block
```

Al poner `flag` al final del todo, ejecuta la acción que se definió en PAT1 o PAT2. Esto es, de imprimir en PAT1 y de no hacerlo en PAT2.

## Imprime líneas entre PAT1 y PAT2 - incluyendo PAT2

```
$ awk 'flag; /PAT1/{flag=1} /PAT2/{flag=0}' fichero
3    - first block
4
PAT2
7    - second block
PAT2
10    - third block
```

Al poner `flag` al principio del todo, ejecuta la acción que se definió previamente. Por tanto, imprime el patrón de clausura pero no el de inicio.

## Imprime líneas entre PAT1 y PAT2 - excluyendo las líneas entre el último PAT1 y el final del fichero si no aparece ningún otro PAT2

Esto está basado en la [solución de Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018573/1983854).

```
awk 'flag{
        if (/PAT2/)
           {printf "%s", buf; flag=0; buf=""}
        else
            buf = buf $0 ORS
     }
     /PAT1/ {flag=1}' fichero
```

En una sola línea:

```
$ awk 'flag{ if (/PAT2/){printf "%s", buf; flag=0; buf=""} else buf = buf $0 ORS}; /PAT1/{flag=1}' fichero
3    - primer bloque
4
7    - segundo bloque

# nótese que el tercer bloque no aparece, pues no hay ningún patrón PAT2 después del último PAT1
```

Esto guarda las líneas seleccionadas en un buffer: a partir del momento en que una línea coincide con el patrón PAT1, va añadiendo todas las líneas hasta que PAT2 se encuentra. En ese momento, imprime las líneas guardadas y vacía el buffer.