# ¿Cómo puedo quedarme con las línas de un bloque solamente si contiene un patrón determinado?

Tags: linux, awk, shell-script

Imaginemos que tengo un fichero así:

```
IIII ---> Marca de inicio de Texto
linea 2
linea 3
linea 4
linea 5
linea 6
linea 7
FFFF --> Marca de Fin de texto

IIII
linea 10
linea 11
linea 12
linea 13
linea 14
linea 15
FFFF

IIII
linea 10
linea 11
linea 12
linea 13
linea 14
linea 15
linea 16
linea 17
linea 18
linea 19
FFFF
```

Si busco con un `grep linea 12` me muestra la línea 12.

Pero lo que quiero exactamente es el fragmento de texto entre IIII y FFFF estando dentro la búsqueda en cuestión.

Es decir, exactamente esto:

```
IIII
linea 10
linea 11
linea 12
linea 13
linea 14
linea 15
FFFF

IIII
linea 10
linea 11
linea 12
linea 13
linea 14
linea 15
linea 16
linea 17
linea 18
linea 19
FFFF
```

con `awk '/IIII/, /FFFF/' texto.txt` tengo todos los fragmentos pero quiero solamente el fragmento que contenga una línea a buscar.

Comment: Es decir que quieres el grupo `III ... FFF` que contenga "linea 12" en él, ¿verdad?

Comment: Por cierto, "linea 12" aparece dos veces aquí. ¿Es correcto? Si es así, la salida debería contener también el segundo bloque, ¿no?

Comment: Dale a [edit] para mejorar la explicación, no pongas info importante en los comentarios sino en la propia pregunta.

Comment: eso es, deberian de salir los 2 bloques

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como bien indicas, las soluciones del tipo `awk '/primer_patrón/,/segundo_patrón/' fichero` no son suficientes. Esto es así porque con ellas imprimes todo lo que hay entre "primer_patrón" y "segundo_patrón" de una forma *irreflexiva*, es decir, sin tener en cuenta qué hay dentro de ese bloque. Esto está resuelto en [¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las líneas entre dos patrones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55221/83), con todas sus posibles variantes.

Y precisamente allí es donde coge complejidad tu problema, pues quieres seleccionar un bloque y, una vez extraído, decidir si quieres imprimirlo en base a si hay otro patrón dentro de él.

Dado que estamos trabajando en Awk, que es un lenguaje que lee línea a línea, debemos buscar algún truquillo para intentar "volver atrás" e imprimir en función de las condiciones. Hagámoslo mediante **buffers**: guardemos todas las líneas de un bloque en una variable y, en paralelo, detectemos si contiene ese otro patrón. Si es así, imprimámoslo; si no, desechémoslo:

```
awk '/III/{flag=1}
     flag{buf = buf $0 ORS}
     /FFF/{flag=0; if(imprimir) print buf; buf=""; impirmir=0}
     flag && /linea 12/{imprimir=1}' fichero
```

Es decir:

- `/III/{flag=1}`
  Si empieza por "III", marca el inicio de la acumulación en el buffer mediante un flag (marca).
- `flag{buf = buf $0 ORS}`
  Si la marca está activa, acumula el contenido en la variable `buf`. Separa las líneas con el delimitador de registros predeterminado (ORS, por defecto salto de línea).
- `flag && /linea 12/{imprimir=1}' fichero`
  Si el flag está activado, es decir, si estamos "grabando" y, además, encontramos el patrón adicional "linea 12", entonces marcamos con un flag que el bloque se debe imprimir.
- `/FFF/{if(imprimir) print buf; buf=""; impirmir=0; flag=0}`
  Cuando llega a la marca de final de bloque, imprime el buffer si se ha encontrado "linea 12". Resetea las variables de marca y el buffer.

Dado tu fichero, esto devolvería:

```
$ awk '/III/{flag=1} flag{buf = buf $0 ORS} flag && /linea 12/{imprimir=1} /FFF/{if(imprimir) print buf; buf=""; impirmir=0; flag=0}' fichero
IIII
linea 10
linea 11
linea 12
linea 13
linea 14
linea 15
FFFF

IIII
linea 10
linea 11
linea 12
linea 13
linea 14
linea 15
linea 16
linea 17
linea 18
linea 19
FFFF
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funciona a la perfección con un dato en particular. Si quiero introducirle el dato que contenga como parametro, en lugar de:

flag && /linea 12/{imprimir=1}' fichero

realizo
flag && /$1/{imprimir=1}' fichero

Pero no me recone la varible. ¿En este caso como puedo realizar? Iria entre comillas? haciendo pruebas ....

Comment: @Ruben si quieres utilizar una variable, debes pasársela a awk con `v` --> `awk -v variable="bla" '$0 ~ variable'`. En este caso, deberías decir `awk -v valor="$1" 'flag && $0 ~ valor {imprimir=1}' fichero`.

Comment: Pruebo de la siguiente manera y me saca todo:

awk -v valor="$1" '/IIII/{flag=1} flag{buf = buf $0 ORS} flag && /valor/{imprimir=1} /FFFF/{if(imprimir) print buf; buf=""; imprimir=0; flag=0}' fichero.log

De esta manera saca de mas .... Como sería? Como habría que poner la variable valor, quizas con $valor?

Comment: @Ruben relee mi comentario anterior :) Usa `$0 ~ valor` y no `/valor/`, pues este último buscará el texto literal "valor".

Comment: Perfecto y 10000 gracias. Ahora bien, si ademas de de buscar la línea, se podria buscar 2 lineas? es decir quedarme con los fragmentos que contengan 2 palabras en diferentes lineas dentro de los parametros de IIII y FFFF

Comment: Me explico, sería como introducir 2 varibles con un AND al AWK ??? Sería posible ????

Comment: @Ruben mi respuesta da unas pautas que, a buen seguro, puedes utilizar para llegar a la solución. Inténtalo y si no te sale publica una nueva pregunta.