# ¿Cómo imprimo las líneas de un bloque si en él aparece un patrón?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Pregunta que surge a partir de una cuestión anterior:

[Filtrar datos con un patrón en AWK después de cierto número de coincidencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407233/filtrar-datos-con-un-patr%c3%b3n-en-awk-despu%c3%a9s-de-cierto-n%c3%bamero-de-coincidencia/407418?noredirect=1#comment729339_407418)

Quiero filtrar los siguientes datos de forma genérica mediante Awk:

```
...
...
$$$$
1
1
$$$$
2
2
$$$$
3
3
$$$$
4
clave
4
$$$$
5
5
$$$$
...
...
```

y supongamos que quiero extraer los datos que están entre el patrón que contiene la palabra clave pero sin saber en que número de patrón nos encontramos.

```
4
clave
4
```

He probado lo siguiente:

```
awk '/^\$\$\$\$/{flag++;next} flag==1 && /clave/'
```

Pensaba que encontraría el primer patrón y mostraría sólo aquellos con la condición, en este caso "clave" pero no es así.

Comment: ¿cuál es la salida deseada? No me queda clara

Comment: El contenido entre dos patrones pero solo con la coincidencia deseada, en este caso la palabra clave. No se si me explico

Comment: es que en este caso `flag` debe ser 4 para que entre en este bloque: `awk '/^\$\$\$\$/{flag++;next} flag==4 && /clave/' fichero`.

Comment: Si te es más práctico para hacer pruebas, saca el 4 afuera y ponlo como variable: `awk -v num_bloque=4 '/^\$\$\$\$/{flag++;next} flag==num_bloque && /clave/' fichero`. O incluso variable Bash: `awk -v num_bloque="$num" '/^\$\$\$\$/{flag++;next} flag==num_bloque && /clave/' fichero`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' tú solución en este caso es buena, pero mi idea sería hacerlo de forma genérica. Sunpongamos que no sabemos entre que número de patrón se encuentra. Lo modifico en la pregunta

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135728/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-quedarme-con-las-l%c3%adnas-de-un-bloque-solamente-si-contiene-un-patr%c3%b3n?rq=1

este tema es muy interesante. Pero de nuevo tengo problemas porque el patrón es el mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `$` como el carácter con el que se separan los registros y simplemente mira si un registro dado tiene "clave" en él:

```
awk -v RS='$' '/clave/' fichero
```

Por defecto, `RS` vale "\n" (salto de línea), por lo que cada registro es una línea. Ahora bien, si lo definimos como "$", cada registro viene a ser lo que buscamos. Entonces, solo es cuestión de mirar en cuál de ellos aparece "clave", que hacemos con `/clave/` y que lanza el comando por defecto de Awk consistente en imprimir el registro actual (`{print $0}`).

Para usar exactamente `$$$$` como separador de registros hay que escaparlo y además incluir "\n" para que coja *exactamente* lo que hay dentro:

```
awk -v RS='\n\\$\\$\\$\\$\n' '/clave/' fichero
```

O, mejor aún ([con ayuda del gran Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895688/1983854)):

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)[$]{4}\n' '/clave/' fichero
```

---

Para opciones más de pico y pala, se trata de ir acumulando en memoria el contenido de los bloques e imprimirlo si resulta que contiene la palabra que queremos:

```
awk '/^\$\$\$\$/ {if (buena) print buf; buena=0; buf="";next}
     {buf = (buf ? buf ORS $0 : $0)}
     /clave/ {buena=1}' fichero
```

Expliquémoslo:

- `/^\$\$\$\$/ {if (buena) print buf; buena=0; buf="";next}` cuando encuentra el separador, imprime el buffer si existe y toca escribirlo. Luego, inicializa para la siguiente iteración.
- `{buf = (buf ? buf ORS $0 : $0)}` acumula el contenido del bloque actual en un buffer.
- `/clave/ {buena=1}` si se encuentra con "clave", da el bloque por bueno con una bandera "buena".

En una línea:

```
$ awk '/^\$\$\$\$/{if (buena) print buf; buena=0; buf="";next} {buf = (buf ? buf ORS $0 : $0)} /clave/ {buena=1}' fichero
4
clave
4
```

Comment: Gran respuesta, ha servido para realizar lo que quería y poder entenderlo. Muchas gracias.