# Buscar entre 2 patrones en una sola linea UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

estoy intentando buscar el contenido entre 2 patrones e idealmente luego guardarlos en un archivo linea a linea.
me explico:
Tengo un archivo de texto plano con el formato:

```
00004A04141216398600  00000000CIR41216  39869999999999CIR   020000
```

el archivo tiene 3 millones aprox de largo todo en una **unica** **linea**, pero de ahi solo necesito sacar cierta informacion.
la idea es obtener la informacion entre dos patrones por ejemplo

```
    INICIO PATRON 00004533A0414121639860 000000000CIR4121639869999999999CI000 FIN PATRON
```

y que quede en otro archivo asi:

```
INICIO PATRON
00004533A0414121639 
860000000000CIR4121639
869999999999CIR020000
FIN PATRON
```

idealmente que si encuentra X cantidad de espacio haga un salto de linea hasta que termine el patron.

he estado probando con sed de esta forma.

```
sed -n  '/INICIO PATRON/,/FIN PATRON/p' entrada*.asc > salida.txt
```

pero esto solo me crea un archivo con todo el contenido, osea, el mismo archivo que entra.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la X cantidad de espacio?

Comment: Por otra parte, ¿no sería más fácil sustituir los espacios por saltos de línea y aplicar lo dicho en [¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las líneas entre dos patrones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55221/83)?

Comment: hola seria definir por ejemplo, si tiene 8 espacios seguidos, hacer salto de linea

Comment: sería bueno tener un [mcve] para que quede claro si el patrón aparece varias veces o no, cuántos espacios seguidos puede haber, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Como aclaras que los patrones tienen espacios, esta vez hago uso de `sed` para procesar la siguiente línea:

```
BLABLA BLA BLa 00004533A0414121639 00004533A0414121639 demas texto INICIO DEL PATRON        00004533A0414121639        860000000000CIR4121639        869999999999CIR020000    FIN DEL PATRON texto extra 0000000000000546565465 004654654654654 06455465465
```

La idea esta vez es separar los patrones y el contenido en grupos:

```
$ sed -r "s/(^.*)(INICIO DEL PATRON)(.*)(FIN DEL PATRON)(.*$)/INICIO_DEL_PATRON\3FIN_DEL_PATRON/" patron.txt | tr -s ' _' '\n '
INICIO DEL PATRON
00004533A0414121639
860000000000CIR4121639
869999999999CIR020000
FIN DEL PATRON
```

---

Asumiendo esta sola línea y usando guion bajo en los patrones (asumo que tal vez el patron real no tenga espacio):

```
BLABLA BLA BLa 00004533A0414121639 00004533A0414121639 demas texto INICIO_PATRON        00004533A0414121639        860000000000CIR4121639        869999999999CIR020000    FIN_PATRON texto extra 0000000000000546565465 004654654654654 06455465465
```

Puedes usar una secuencia `grep` + `tr`, asi:

```
$ grep -o "INICIO_PATRON.*FIN_PATRON"  patron.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n'
INICIO_PATRON
00004533A0414121639
860000000000CIR4121639
869999999999CIR020000
FIN_PATRON
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta, el patron tiene espacio(como se muestra en el POST) pudiendo ser 3 o mas  palabaras con espacios:
COMIENZO DEL PATRON hdhdq1286dg21 FIN DEL PATRON

Comment: Hola, se repite el patron varias veces o solo esperas encontrarlo una vez? Además, se puede reemplazar el patron en el archivo final o debe conservarse ? es decir, podria reemplazar `COMIENZO DEL PATRON` por `COMIENZO_DEL_PATRON` en el archivo final?

Comment: el patron es unico por archivo, realmente si viene con espacio, se puede reemplazar por "_" ya que lo que interesa finalmente es el contenido entre los patrones

Comment: @FabianFeriks, Vale, he modificado la respuesta, usando `sed` funciona con o sin espacios

Answer (score 0):

Voy a usar el siguiente archivo:

```
masd palabras INICIO_PATRON 00004533A0414121639860 000000000CIR4121639869999999999CI000 FIN_PATRON otras palabras masd palabras INICIO_PATRON 11114533A0414121639861 000011111DFR4121639869999999999CI222 FIN_PATRON otras palabras mas INICIO_PATRON 22224533A0414121639860 498375648CIR4121639869954543462CI000 FIN_PATRON otras palsasd
```

Es decir, en una línea, hay un patron de la forma

```
palabras1+patron inicio+cadena importante+patronfinal+palabras
```

y se repite ese patrón en la misma línea.

Para la primera aproximación, en el caso donde sea un patrón fijo y además que **no contenga espacios**, usaré `awk`.

```
awk \
-v in_pat="INICIO_PATRON" \
-v fin_pat="FIN_PATRON" '{
    imprimir = 0
    for ( i=1; i<NF; i++ ) {
        if ( $i == in_pat || imprimir ) 
            imprimir = 1
        if ( $i == fin_pat ) {
            imprimir = 0
            print $i
            print "========================"
        }
        if ( imprimir )
            print $i
    }
}' archivo
```

Cuyo resultado da por el estilo lo siguiente.

```
INICIO_PATRON
00004533A0414121639860
000000000CIR4121639869999999999CI000
FIN_PATRON
========================
INICIO_PATRON
11114533A0414121639861
000011111DFR4121639869999999999CI222
FIN_PATRON
========================
INICIO_PATRON
22224533A0414121639860
498375648CIR4121639869954543462CI000
FIN_PATRON
========================
```

En cambio, si el archivo tiene un patrón que se puede obtener con una expresión regular, se me ocurre una sencilla expresión con `grep`, sólo que no saldrá el patrón de forma "natural" con un *header* y un *footer*.

```
grep -oP 'INICIO_PATRON\K.*?(?=FIN_PATRON)' archivo | xargs -n1
```

Y si el patrón es una cadena fija.

```
 grep -oP '(?<=INICIO_PATRON).*?(?=FIN_PATRON)' archivo | xargs -n1
```

Cuya explicación es que `\K` indica que la coincidencia va a comenzar a partir de ese punto, `.*` indica que va a coincidir con todos los caracteres después de ese patrón, `?` después de `.*` es que va a coincidir con la menor cantidad de caracteres, es decir, en modo *non greedy* y `(?=FIN_PATRON)` indica que tiene que coincidir siempre y cuando haya un patrón `FIN_PATRON` subsiguiente.

En cambio, `(?<=INICIO_PATRON).*` empareja lo que suceda a la cadena "INICIO_PATRON"

Esta última aproximación funciona con espacios en el patrón, sólo que el resultado (ya con el uso de `xargs`) daría de la forma:

```
00004533A0414121639860
000000000CIR4121639869999999999CI000
11114533A0414121639861
000011111DFR4121639869999999999CI222
22224533A0414121639860
498375648CIR4121639869954543462CI000
```

Es decir, sin el `INICIO PATRON` ni el `FIN PATRON`, sino inmediatamente con lo que esté entre ellos.

Ya si quieres que esté formateado de esa manera, puedes hacer algo como.

```
grep -oP 'INICIO PATRON[[:space:]]*\K.*?(?=[[:space:]]*FIN PATRON)' archivo | tr " " "|" | xargs -I {} bash -c 'printf "%s|%s|%s\n" "INICIO PATRON" "{}" "FIN PATRON"' | xargs -n1 -d "|"
```

Y ya resultará en algo de la forma.

```
INICIO PATRON
00004533A0414121639860
000000000CIR4121639869999999999CI000
FIN PATRON
INICIO PATRON
11114533A0414121639861
000011111DFR4121639869999999999CI222
FIN PATRON
INICIO PATRON
22224533A0414121639860
498375648CIR4121639869954543462CI000
FIN PATRON
```