# Filtrar datos con un patrón en AWK después de cierto número de coincidencia

Tags: linux, regex, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Quiero filtrar los siguientes datos mediante AWK:

```
0
0
$$$$
1
1
$$$$
2
2
$$$$
3
3
$$$$
4
4
$$$$
5
5
```

y supongamos que quiero extraer los datos  sólo entre el segundo patrón y el tercero:

```
2
2
```

No consigo que seleccione mediante "$" y que comience en la coincidencia que me interesa.

Lo único que tengo, o con lo que he arrancado es:

```
awk '/patron/{flag=1;next} /patron/{flag=0}flag' archivo
```

Por patron se entiende en este caso $$$$, pero como comento con anterioridad no consigo que lo identifque.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner lo que haz hecho en `awk`?

Comment: `cat archivo| awk '/patron/{flag=1;next} /patron/{flag=0}flag'`

Pero no consigo que identifique el caracter $$$$ y tampoco sé como comenzar en la coincidencia que quiera.

Comment: Estoy a punto de terminar una respuesta que creo que te puede ayudar. De todas maneras, pon ese comentario en tu publicación para que otros puedan ofrecer sus diferentes puntos de vista. Por cierto, ¿A qué te refieres con `patron`? ¿A un patrón de verdad o a la palabra "patron"?

Comment: A un patrón de verdad, en este caso $$$$. Intentaba ponerlo de forma genérica ya que con $$$$ no consigo que funcione, entiendo que interpreta otra cosa. Mil gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ibas bien con la expresión que planteabas, solamente debes exprimirla un poco más:

```
awk '/patron/{flag++;next} flag==2' fichero
```

En tu caso concreto: `awk '/^\$\$\$\$/{flag++;next} flag==2'`.

¿Qué hace esto?

- `/patron/{flag++;next}` cuando encuentra el patrón, incrementa la variable `flag`, que hace algo así como de bandera. Como nunca querremos imprimir esta línea, saltamos a la siguiente con `next`. El patrón en tu caso puede ser `^\$\$\$\$`, que quiere decir "la línea empieza por $$$$".
- `flag==2` utilizando el hecho que Awk ejecuta `{print $0}` por defecto cuando encuentra un valor cierto, podemos omitirlo. Por tanto, simplemente se trata de poner una condición lógica que solo se cumpla cuando nos interese. En este caso, indicamos `flag==2`, que quiere decir que el contador de patrones está exactamente a 2. Es decir, estamos indicando que imprima cuando haya entrada en el 2.º bloque de `$$$$`.

Comment: Gran respuesta.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta.

Comment: Me surge una duda de como seguir implementándolo que no consigo modificar, no se si plantearla como otra duda o indicarla aquí. La comento:

¿Y si quisiese que sólo mostrase las líneas entre el patrón pero que contengan por ejemplo el número 4? Es decir que contenga una condición para mostrarse.

Comment: @uland a bote pronto se me ocurre escribir `awk '/patron/{flag++;next} flag==2 && /4/' fichero`. Con esto imprimirá las líneas que aparezcan después del 2.º patrón que contengan "4". Recomiendo leer también [¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las líneas entre dos patrones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55221/83).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' lo había visto sí, y me sirvió de gran utilidad en un caso similar. Seguiré dandole unas vueltas al tema de la condición, lo que comentas ya lo había intentado indicándolo desde el primer patrón que se encuentre pero de momento no funciona . Gracias!

Comment: @uland plantea pues una nueva pregunta, seguro que es bien interesante.

Answer (score 3):

Como se ha recapitulado en otras publicaciones dentro de este mismo sitio, `awk` funciona de la manera `patrón{acción}`. Donde la acción por defecto es imprimir el registro (más no renglón) entero.

Saber esto nos permite desencadenar todo el poder de `awk` y evitarnos escribir ciertas cosas. Sin embargo, es necesario saber esto para entender la correspondencia entre el código y la salida.

Con el siguiente ejemplo, obtendremos lo que esté entre el **segundo** y **tercer patrón** de la forma `$*`:

```
$ awk \
    -v ncoin=2 '
/\$+/{ 
    if (++coin == ncoin) start = NR
    else if (coin == ncoin + 1) stop = NR
}
NR == stop {exit}
start && NR > start
' archivo
```

Resultando en:

```
2 
2
```

En caso de que se quiera otro, sólo se debe de cambiar el valor de la variable `ncoin`.

En esta caso, utilzamos el parametro `-v` que nos permite definir la variable `ncoin` con el valor 2 para servirnos como indicador del número de coincidencia que queremos.

Después, dentro del script de `awk`, utilizamos tres patrones:

1. La expresión regular `/\$+/`, que indica "el registro que tenga **uno o más** caracteres '$'"
2. La expresión lógica `NR == stop`, que indica "cuando el número de registro sea igual a lo almacenado en la variable *stop*"
3. La expresión lógica `start && NR > start`, que indica "cuando la variable *start* sea diferente de cero y el número de registro sea mayor a lo almacenado en la variable *start*"

**¡En ese orden (al menos en mi propuesta)!**

Antes de comenzar con lo que hay dentro de las acciones, hay que recordar que `awk` contiene variables predefinidas con información importante. Una de ellas es `NR` que indica el número de registros "vistos" hasta el momento. Que, a mi juicio y de otros, es una fuerte equivalencia entre esta variable y **el número de renglón correspondiente**.

Después de esta recapitulación, dentro del **primer patron encontrado**, la acción realizada es incrementar la variable `coin` en 1, al compararla con la variable que definimos nosotros como `ncoin`.

Si son iguales, es lo mismo que decir que tal número de coincidencia es igual al número de coincidencia que queríamos.

Al dar por verdadero esto, a la variable `start` se le asigna el valor del renglón en el que fue encontrado.

Después, si no lo es, preguntamos si aquel número, **ya incrementado**, corresponde al número de coincidencia deseado más uno; es decir, al número de renglón de la siguiente coincidencia.

Al dar por verdadero esto, a la variable `stop` se le asigna el valor del renglón en el que fue encontrado.

En el segundo patrón, preguntamos si la variable `stop`, que incrementamos en la primera acción, es la misma que el actual registro.

En caso de ser cierto, nos salimos del script.

En el tercer patrón, preguntamos si la variable `start`, que asignamos tambión en la primera acción, es diferente de cero y su valor almacenado coincide con el número de registro. Notemos como no definimos una acción a diferencia de las anteriores. Esto le indica a `awk` que imprima el actual registro.

Entonces, con todo esto, se imprime lo que esté entre el patrón deseado y el siguiente. Además, el programa sale después de encontrar el siguiente patrón.

**Nota**: En caso de intercambiar el patron 1 con el 3, esto permitiría que se imprimiera este patrón debido a la condición `NR > start`. Por esto es que la condición de salida va antes.
Si se desea evitar esto, tan sólo habría que añadir a la condición `start && NR > start && NR != stop`

Comment: Funciona a la perfección extraplandolo al caso que necesitaba y gran explicación. Trataré de entenderla al completo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bien explicado y resuelto. Nótese de todos modos que se puede exprimir un poco más el Awk y limitarlo a apenas un `awk '/patron/{flag++;next} flag==2' fichero`, que explico en mi respuesta.